# Is parallelism in computer science always directly tied to the number of processor cores?

Tags: multi-core, computer-architecture, threads, parallel-processing

Specific to the Java programming language, would it be accurate to say that two threads can be concurrent, but can only truly be run in parallel if there are two or more cores?

Comment: No, because one core can sometimes run multiple threads. See Hyper-Threading.

Comment: My understanding is that hyper-threading only improves parallelism, but doesn't give you parallelism where it didn't exist before. To me, meaning if you didn't have more than one core hyper-threading wouldn't do anything for you.

Comment: Nope, each physical core consists of two logical cores which share many resources. It's not as good are two physical cores, but it can be better then just one "normal" core: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading#Overview
It is true the using hyper threading needs you to program for it though, so maybe that's what you were thinking of.

Comment: The answer really depends on what you mean by concurrent.  Due to thread and process scheduling, modern operating systems give the appearance of concurrency even if the machine has a single core.

Comment: @heavyd Multiple processes performing some function on an in memory resource (or collection of resources), but not simultaneously.